# How to get rid of the two vertex?

Tags: vertices

I have established an edge route but have two extra vertex. How to get rid of them? I tried to connect them with the last one but the result is worse. I can't add new loop cut because I need a curve

[image]

[image: gun model]

[image]

Here is the next problem

[image: here is the next problem]

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing <kbd>X</kbd> on the 2 vertices that need to be deleted, and try *Delete Vertices*.

If that doesn't work, press <kbd>X</kbd> again, but click on *Dissolve Vertices* instead.